# How to use Arial in PDF using TCPDF without embedding

Tags: php, fonts, embedding, tcpdf

I have successfully added the font `Arial` to `TCPDF`, however the filesize is large due to it embedding the font.  I would have thought `Arial` was a standard font on the vast majority of users machines, so is there a way of it working by using `Arial` if available, then `Helvetica` if not, then any sans-serif font as a backup?

Comment: The font isn't that big!  How small do you want this PDF to be?  I believe there is a way in PDF to only include the glyphs you are using, but I'm not sure how to do that in TCPDF.

Comment: It did make the pdf much bigger by percentage - 500KB for Helvetica to 2.5MB-4MB for Arial depending on what glyphs I include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I remove all `arial` files in the fonts folder other than the ones ending in `.php`, the filesize drops to around 500KB, just like the other core fonts in tcpdf.  I would imagine that this means they are now not embedded and will revert to another sans-serif font on the users machine if they don't have arial.

Comment: You can verify this in the properties dialog within Acrobat Reader.

Answer (score 3):

You can subset the font, which embeds only the glyphs that are actually used in your document. That'll save some space as Arial has glyphs for a very very large swath of the Unicode character space.

it's the last argument in the [setFont()](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php) call (scroll to the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks - that did help it get down from 4MB to 2.5MB for the PDF, but that's still much larger than the 500KB for Helvetica, which is a similar, but core, font.